# why doesn't GCC optimize trivial function that always return false

Tags: c, gcc

Why does x86-64 gcc 13.1 with the -O3 optimization option not optimize the `test2` function to always return false, while it optimizes `test1` correctly?

```
bool test1(int a, int b) {
    return (a >= b + 2) && (a < b + 1);
}

bool test2(int a, int b){
    return (a >= b + 3) && (a < b + 2);
}
```

`test1` is optimized correctly to always return false, resulting in the following assembly:

```
test1(int, int):
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

However, `test2` is not optimized as expected and generates the following assembly:

```
test2(int, int):
        lea     edx, [rsi+2]
        xor     eax, eax
        cmp     edx, edi
        jge     .L3
        add     esi, 1
        cmp     esi, edi
        setge   al
.L3:
        ret
```

Is there a reason for this difference in optimization behavior and, if so, what is it?

Comment: What OS?  Just in case it makes a difference.

Comment: This is a better question for the gcc team's mailing lists than for here; they'd be equipped to actually fix the problem or explain why they chose a design that stops where it does. Given the scope that SO only covers "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face" -- how would an answer change how you go about the practice of programming?

Comment: The overflow result is only guarantied for `unsigned`. What happens if `b`is `MAX_INT`? It's an undefined behavior. The compiler can consider a valid result only if `b` is less than `MAX_INT - 3` and any result in undefined behavior cases and optimize as a `false` result. But because of the UB, may not do the optimization.  For internal reasons, an optimized code is produced in first sample.

Comment: Interestingly Clang doesn't do the optimization for either version (https://godbolt.org/z/j98boYj6Y). Also, GCC has an issue specifically with the `a < b + 2` part. `a < b + 1` works as expected.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I tried it on https://godbolt.org/z/78EYerb6v . When I tested on Ubuntu 22.04 with GCC 11.3.0, neither of them were optimized to return false.

Comment: @dalfaB If it is UB then that's exactly what allows the compiler to ignore the case for optimization purposes and just do it anyway.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If this is just bug or mistake, I will do so but just wondering if it is the case.

Comment: @user17732522 *If it is UB...* Seems likely - although in the reverse, apparently.  Adding `-fwrapv` to remove the UB on overflow causes both to **not** be optimized using the Godbolt link the OP posted above.  It looks like it's the *presence* of UB on overflow that's allowing `test1` to be optimized.

Comment: Compiler optimize if it can. Because of the UB, it's not simple to say in all defined cases the result is `false`. Most of compilers do not optimize both cases because too complex. All compilers try to optimize more and more cases, but very simple code can be hard to detect. I did not try, but I'm sure all compiler will optimize if the type was `unsigned int`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That's what I intended to say. Because it is UB the situation that would cause overflow can be ignored to determine optimization validity and the optimization can be applied as it is trivial to see that the expression is always false if no overflow/wraparound happens. With wraparound the optimization can't be applied because there are some values for `a` and `b` which would result in true.

Comment: @dalfaB UB makes it _easier_ for the compiler to optimize. Because of the UB it is trivial to prove that the expressions are _always_ false for all permitted inputs. With `unsigned int` the optimization would _not_ be valid.

Comment: @user17732522, it's trivial for you (and for me), but for an algorithm trying to find the simplest expression, I not sure it's simple.

Comment: Maybe gcc is not smart enough to optimize the functions.  gcc doesn't even optimize following function though there is no possibility of integer overflow. ```bool test3(int a, int b) { return (b < 0) && (a >= b + 3) && (a < b + 2); }```